# C++ BST remove: deleted a whole sub-tree when removing a node with 2 children

Tags: c++, recursion, struct, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing a C++ binary search tree and is trying to write a function that removes a certain node. The code works well for a leaf node (no children) and node with one child, but every time when it tries to delete a node with 2 children it will delete a whole sub-tree.

```
struct Node {
    string key;
    string otherdata;
    Node* left; 
    Node* right;
};
typedef Node* bst;
```

the above are declared structure for bst. 
the following is (part of) the function:

```
void delete_bst_node (bst& root, string key) { 

    if(...){
        //...code to setup edge cases
    }

    else if((root->key)>key){
        delete_bst_node(root->left, key);
    }else if((root->key)<key){
        delete_bst_node(root->right, key);
    }

    //and then start deleting:

    else if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL){
        delete root;
        root=nullptr;
        //no child case, works fine
    }else if (NULL!=root->left && NULL==root->right){
        Node* temp=root;
        root=root->left;
        delete temp;
        //1 child case 1, works fine
    }else if(NULL!=root->right && NULL==root->left){
        Node* temp=root;
        root=root->right;
        delete temp;
        //1 child case 2, works fine
    }else{
        Node* temp =find_max_of_tree(root->left);
        root->key=temp->key;
        delete_bst_node(root->left, temp->key);     
        //**here it doesn't work.** 
}
    }
```

}

When I tried to test a 2-children case:
[my input tree is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhRhP.png)

if I delete "4" the output is "4  8  9" using a bst print function(print from smallest to largest).

if I delete "2" the output is "2  3  4  8  9".

from these two examples i found **my code is deleting the whole left subtree of whatever node i try to delete.**

In the 2 children deletion case i tried to find the largest node in left sub-tree using a find_max_of_tree function, and copy the value of that node into root node (the one i want to be deleted), then delete the original max node of left tree using recursion, either using no child case or single child case.

I watched and read a loot of resources on line but failed to find why this occurs. and after i debug it for a long time i found [this youtube video at time 16:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcULXE7ViZw) and our logic is basically the same but my code isn't working :(

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks! :D

edit: for now i'm not considering any repetitive entries

Comment: I think you might want to replace the node with the least node in the right subtree since if you use the greatest node in the left subtree, there might be another node in the left subtree that is equal to the greatest node. This will cause problems since anything equal to the node should be in the right subtree.

Comment: @FeiXiang thanks for your comment. For now I'm just considering the case where there isn't any repetitive keys, but this would still be a good suggestion. The thing is I was using the right subtree method but that one doesn't solve the problem here.

Comment: Try checking your logic by pretending to explain it to someone, and stepping through it with a debugger.